# Simplify Boolean (X + Y)(X' + Z) = XZ + X'Y

Tags: boolean-logic

I am trying to solve this equation but I get z(x + y) + yx'. I am also wondering if this counts as the communicative boolean law .

Comment: If you think about it, it has to be true:  With (X + Y)(X' + Z) if X=true then (true + Y)(false + Z) which is Z and if X=false then (false + Y)(true + Z) which is Y.  So XZ is the first term and X'Y is the second: XZ + X'Y

Answer (score 2):

```
(X + Y)(X' + Z)
XX' + X'Y + XZ + YZ     Distributive law (twice)
F + X'Y + XZ + YZ       Complement law: AA' = F
X'Y + XZ + YZ           Identity law: F + A = A
X'Y + XZ + YZT          Identity law: A = AT
X'Y + XZ + YZ(X + X')   Complement law: T = (A + A')
X'Y + XZ + XYZ + X'YZ   Distributive law
X'Y + X'YZ + XZ + XYZ   Commutative law (twice)
X'YT + X'YZ + XZT + XYZ Identity law (twice): A = AT
X'Y(T + Z) + XZ(T + Y)  Distributive law (twice)
X'YT + XZT              Dominant law (twice): T + A = T
X'Y + XZ                Identity law (twice): AT = A
XZ + X'Y                Commutative law
```